# Paperclip conditional styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From `upload.html.erb` I am submitting a form with data - including an image and crop information (x and y coordinates, width and height) - to a controller method called `update_image`. I then want to pass this information on over to the model (`picture.rb`) and save a cropped version of this image.

I'm using Rails 5 and Paperclip to store images. I've ran into the following two problems which I don't seem to be able to solve:

1. How to access the crop information data inside my model? I don't want to save the crop information in the database.
2. How to crop images *only* if crop information is present? (I want to use the same model for regular file uploads from another form that doesn't have the crop functionality)

Help is greatly appreciated!

**upload.html.erb**

```
<form action="/update_image" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="image" />
  <input type="hidden" name="crop_x" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="crop_y" value="5" />
  <input type="hidden" name="crop_width" value="200" />
  <input type="hidden" name="crop_height" value="100" />
</form>
```

**upload_controller.rb**

```
def update_image
  picture = Picture.new(image: params[:image])
end
```

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    cropped: "-crop #{@crop_w}x#{@crop_h}+#{@crop_x}+#{@crop_y}",
    thumb: "100x100>"
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for dynamic styles.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :crop_needed
  has_attached_file :image, styles: Proc.new { |clip| clip.instance.attachment_sizes }

 def attachment_sizes
    crop_needed ? {
      cropped: "-crop #{@crop_w}x#{@crop_h}+#{@crop_x}+#{@crop_y}",
      thumb: "100x100>"
    } : {thumb: "100x100>"}
 end
end
```

From the controller where you need cropping:

```
def update_image
  picture = Picture.new
  picture.crop_needed = true if params[:crop_x].present?
  picture.image = params[:image]
  picture.save
end
```

From the other controller where you do not need cropping, just set `crop_needed` to false.